# Xamarin View Not Refreshing

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am having some problems with my Xamarin XAML page and its viewmodel.

I have written the code with a bunch of methods which are executed via commands from the XAML.

Functionally its all working as desired. However, the view is not refreshing when the methods have finished executing. So despite inserting things and removing things from my observable collections (via an API call update), and having a notifypropertychanged event, the page doesn't reload.

Any ideas?

**ViewModel** (Some properties omitted to fit the character limit for a post)

```
namespace TechsportiseApp.ViewModels
{
    public class ResultsProcessViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public ICommand AddTimingCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddScanCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand DeleteTimingCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand DeleteScanCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand PublishCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand LoadResultsCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand MissingFinisherCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand MissingTimingCommand { get; set; }

        public int RaceId { get; set; }
        public DateTime RaceDate { get; set; }

        //public ResultsViewModel(Race race)
        public ResultsProcessViewModel(Race race)
        {
            AddTimingCommand = new Command(AddTiming);
            AddScanCommand = new Command(AddScan);
            DeleteTimingCommand = new Command<int>(DeleteTiming);
            DeleteScanCommand = new Command<int>(DeleteScan);
            PublishCommand = new Command<string>(Publish);
            LoadResultsCommand = new Command<int>(LoadResults);
            MissingFinisherCommand = new Command(MissingFinisher);
            MissingTimingCommand = new Command(MissingTiming);

            Invalid = false;

            AddTimingVisibility = false;
            AddScanVisibility = false;
            AddVisibility = true;
            PublishProvisionalVisibility = false;
            PublishFinalVisibility = false;
            IsBusy = false;
            RaceId = race.Id;
            RaceDate = race.RaceDate;
            RaceStartTime = Convert.ToDateTime(race.RaceStartTime);
            Scans = ScansAPI.GetScans(RaceId);
            Timings = TimingsAPI.GetTimings(RaceId);
            Entries = EntriesAPI.GetEntries(RaceId);
            LoadResults(RaceId);
        }



        ObservableCollection<Result> _results;
        public ObservableCollection<Result> Results
        {
            get
            {
                return _results;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_results != value)
                {
                    _results = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Results");
                }
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Scan> _scans;
        public ObservableCollection<Scan> Scans
        {
            get
            {
                return _scans;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_scans != value)
                {
                    _scans = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Scans");
                }
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<Timing> _timings;
        public ObservableCollection<Timing> Timings
        {
            get
            {
                return _timings;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_timings != value)
                {
                    _timings = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Timings");
                }
            }

        }

        ObservableCollection<RaceEntry> _entries;
        public ObservableCollection<RaceEntry> Entries
        {
            get
            {
                return _entries;
            }
            set
            {
                if (_entries != value)
                {
                    _entries = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Entries");
                }
            }
        }



        ObservableCollection<Race> _races;
        public ObservableCollection<Race> Races
        {
            get
            {
                try
                {
                    var racelist = RacesAPI.GetRaces();
                    var sortedracelist = new ObservableCollection<Race>(racelist.OrderBy(c => c.Name));
                    var racecount = racelist.Count();
                    if (racecount == 0)
                    {
                        RaceCountZero = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RaceCountZero = false;
                    }

                    return racelist;
                }
                catch
                {
                    Invalid = true;
                    ValidationError = "Error getting Race List. No internet connection available.";
                }


                return _races;


            }
            set
            {
                if (_races != value)
                {
                    _races = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Races");
                }
            }
        }

        string _aboveBelow;
        public string AboveBelow
        {
            get { return _aboveBelow; }
            set
            {
                if (_aboveBelow == value)
                    return;

                _aboveBelow = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AboveBelow");
            }
        }

        string _aboveBelowPosition;
        public string AboveBelowPosition
        {
            get { return _aboveBelowPosition; }
            set
            {
                if (_aboveBelowPosition == value)
                    return;

                _aboveBelowPosition = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AboveBelowPosition");
            }
        }

        string _addHH;
        public string AddHH
        {
            get { return _addHH; }
            set
            {
                if (_addHH == value)
                    return;

                _addHH = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddHH");
            }
        }

        string _addMM;
        public string AddMM
        {
            get { return _addMM; }
            set
            {
                if (_addMM == value)
                    return;

                _addMM = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddMM");
            }
        }

        string _addSS;
        public string AddSS
        {
            get { return _addSS; }
            set
            {
                if (_addSS == value)
                    return;

                _addSS = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("AddSS");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        void AddTiming()
        {
            AddScanVisibility = false;
            AddTimingVisibility = !AddTimingVisibility;
        }

        void AddScan()
        {
            AddScanVisibility = !AddScanVisibility;
            AddTimingVisibility = false;
        }

        void MissingFinisher()
        {
            //Do stuff when deleting a scan. It needs to do all this in the observable collection. Then when we submit, we'll update all scans, timings etc with whats in the collection
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var scancount = Scans.Count();

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = true);
                    var IsThereConnection = GlobalFunctions.CheckForInternetConnection();

                    if (IsThereConnection == false)
                        throw new Exception("You cannot add a scan whilst you are offline");
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MissingBib))
                        throw new Exception("You must enter a bib number");                  
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AboveBelow))
                        throw new Exception("You must choose if you are adding the bib above or below");
                    else if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(AboveBelowPosition))
                        throw new Exception("You must enter the position you are inserting " + AboveBelow);
                    else if (Convert.ToInt32(AboveBelowPosition) > scancount)
                        throw new Exception("The position you have chosen to insert above or below does not exist. Please enter a valid value");
                    else if (Convert.ToInt32(AboveBelowPosition) < 1)
                        throw new Exception("The position you have chosen to insert above or below does not exist. Please enter a valid value");
                    //We are good to go
                    else
                    {
                        var InsertedSequence = new int();
                        var abovebelow = Scans.SingleOrDefault(i => i.Position == Convert.ToInt32(AboveBelowPosition));
                        var abposition = Convert.ToInt32(AboveBelowPosition);
                        if (AboveBelow == "Above")
                        {
                            InsertedSequence = abovebelow.Sequence + 5;
                        }
                        else if (AboveBelow == "Below")
                        {
                            InsertedSequence = abovebelow.Sequence - 5;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                        //Need to add resequencing and reallocation of position numbers
                        var scan = new ScanPost
                        {
                            RaceId = RaceId,
                            BibNumber = MissingBib,
                            Sequence = InsertedSequence,
                            Position = abposition,
                            Reorder = true,
                            Status = 0
                        };

                        var createscan = ScansAPI.CreateScan(scan);

                        if (createscan.Code != "Created")
                            throw new Exception("Error creating scan");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        ValidationError = ex.Message;
                        Invalid = true;
                    });

                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = false);
                    LoadResults(RaceId);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Results");
                }
            });
        }

        void MissingTiming()
        {
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var timingcount = Timings.Count();

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = true);
                    var IsThereConnection = GlobalFunctions.CheckForInternetConnection();

                    if (IsThereConnection == false)
                        throw new Exception("You cannot add a timing whilst you are offline");
                    //We are good to go
                    else
                    {
                        if (AddHH == "") { AddHH = "0"; }
                        if (AddMM == "") { AddMM = "0"; }
                        if (AddSS == "") { AddSS = "0"; }

                        var ManualEndTime = RaceStartTime.AddHours(Convert.ToDouble(AddHH))
                                                        .AddMinutes(Convert.ToDouble(AddMM))
                                                        .AddSeconds(Convert.ToDouble(AddSS));

                        var timing = new TimingPost
                           {
                               RaceId = RaceId,
                               StartTime = RaceStartTime,
                               EndTime = ManualEndTime,
                               Reorder = true,
                               Position = 0,
                               Status = 0
                           };

                        var createtiming = TimingsAPI.CreateTiming(timing);

                        if (createtiming.Code != "Created")
                            throw new Exception("Error creating timing");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        ValidationError = ex.Message;
                        Invalid = true;
                    });

                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = false);
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => LoadResults(RaceId));
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => OnPropertyChanged("Results"));
                }
            });

        }

        void DeleteTiming(int timingid)
        {
            //Do stuff when deleting a timing. It needs to do all this in the observable collection. Then when we submit, we'll update all scans, timings etc with whats in the collection
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = true);
                    var IsThereConnection = GlobalFunctions.CheckForInternetConnection();

                    if (IsThereConnection == false)
                        throw new Exception("You cannot delete a timing whilst you are offline");

                    //We are good to go
                    else
                    {
                        var deletetiming = TimingsAPI.DeleteTiming(timingid);

                        if (deletetiming.Code != "NoContent")
                            throw new Exception("Error deleting timing");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        ValidationError = ex.Message;
                        Invalid = true;

                    });

                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = false);
                    LoadResults(RaceId);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Timings");
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => LoadResults(RaceId));
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => OnPropertyChanged("Timings"));
                }
            });
        }

        void DeleteScan(int scanid)
        {

            //Do stuff when deleting a scan. It needs to do all this in the observable collection. Then when we submit, we'll update all scans, timings etc with whats in the collection
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = true);
                    var IsThereConnection = GlobalFunctions.CheckForInternetConnection();

                    if (IsThereConnection == false)
                        throw new Exception("You cannot delete a scan whilst you are offline");

                    //We are good to go
                    else
                    {
                        var deletetiming = TimingsAPI.DeleteTiming(scanid);

                        if (deletetiming.Code != "NoContent")
                            throw new Exception("Error deleting scan");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        ValidationError = ex.Message;
                        Invalid = true;

                    });

                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = false);
                    LoadResults(RaceId);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Results");
                }
            });


        }

        void Publish(string status)
        {

            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var publish = new Publish();
                    publish.RaceId = RaceId;
                    publish.ResultStatus = status;

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = true);
                    var IsThereConnection = GlobalFunctions.CheckForInternetConnection();

                    if (IsThereConnection == false)
                        throw new Exception("You cannot publish results whilst you are offline");

                    //We are good to go
                    else
                    {
                        var publishrace = RacesAPI.PublishRace(publish);

                        if (publishrace.Code != "NoContent")
                            throw new Exception("Error publishing race");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                    {
                        ValidationError = ex.Message;
                        Invalid = true;

                    });

                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = false);
                    LoadResults(RaceId);
                    OnPropertyChanged("Results");
                }
            });


        }



        void LoadResults(int raceid)
        {


            var results = new ObservableCollection<Result>();



            //Start with the timings
            foreach (Timing timing in Timings)
            {
                var result = new Result();

                //Basic details
                result.RaceId = RaceId;
                result.RaceDate = RaceDate;
                result.Status = "Processing";

                //Timing Data
                result.TimingId = timing.Id;
                result.TimingPosition = timing.Position;
                result.TimingStatus = timing.Status;
                result.StartTime = timing.StartTime;
                result.EndTime = timing.EndTime;

                var elapsed = result.EndTime - result.StartTime;

                string elapsedhours = elapsed.Hours.ToString();
                string elapsedminutes = elapsed.Minutes.ToString();
                string elapsedseconds = elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
                string elapsedmillis;
                if (elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString().Length > 2)
                {
                    elapsedmillis = elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
                }
                else
                {
                    elapsedmillis = elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString();
                }




                if (elapsedhours.Length == 1) { elapsedhours = "0" + elapsedhours; }
                if (elapsedminutes.Length == 1) { elapsedminutes = "0" + elapsedminutes; }
                if (elapsedseconds.Length == 1) { elapsedseconds = "0" + elapsedseconds; }
                if (elapsedmillis.Length == 1) { elapsedmillis = "0" + elapsedmillis; }



                if((elapsedhours == "00"))
                {
                    result.Elapsed = elapsedminutes + ":" + elapsedseconds + "." + elapsedmillis;
                }
                else 
                {
                    result.Elapsed = elapsedhours + ":" + elapsedminutes + ":" + elapsedseconds + "." + elapsedmillis;
                }


                results.Add(result);
            }

            //Add in the scans
            foreach (Result result1 in results)
            {
                var scan = Scans.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Position == result1.TimingPosition);
                if (scan != null)
                {
                    result1.ScanId = scan.Id;
                    result1.ScanPosition = scan.Position;
                    result1.ScanStatus = scan.Status;
                    result1.ScanBibNumber = scan.BibNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    result1.ScanId = 0;
                    result1.ScanPosition = 0;
                    result1.ScanStatus = 99;
                    result1.ScanBibNumber = "UNKNOWN";
                }
            }

            //Add any scans which there are no times for (Higher than count)
            var timingscount = Timings.Count();
            var notimescans = new ObservableCollection<Scan>();
            foreach (Scan scan in Scans)
            {
                if (scan.Position > timingscount)
                {
                    var newresult = new Result();

                    newresult.RaceId = RaceId;
                    newresult.RaceDate = RaceDate;
                    newresult.Status = "Processing";
                    newresult.ScanId = scan.Id;
                    newresult.ScanPosition = scan.Position;
                    newresult.ScanStatus = scan.Status;
                    newresult.ScanBibNumber = scan.BibNumber;

                    newresult.TimingId = 0;
                    newresult.TimingPosition = 99999;
                    newresult.TimingStatus = 99;
                    newresult.StartTime = RaceStartTime;
                    newresult.EndTime = RaceStartTime;

                    var elapsed = newresult.EndTime - newresult.StartTime;

                    string elapsedhours = elapsed.Hours.ToString();
                    string elapsedminutes = elapsed.Minutes.ToString();
                    string elapsedseconds = elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
                    string elapsedmillis = elapsed.Milliseconds.ToString();

                    if (elapsedhours.Length == 1) { elapsedhours = "0" + elapsedhours; }
                    if (elapsedminutes.Length == 1) { elapsedminutes = "0" + elapsedminutes; }
                    if (elapsedseconds.Length == 1) { elapsedseconds = "0" + elapsedseconds; }
                    if (elapsedmillis.Length == 1) { elapsedmillis = "0" + elapsedmillis; }

                    if ((elapsedhours == "00"))
                    {
                        newresult.Elapsed = elapsedminutes + ":" + elapsedseconds + "." + elapsedmillis;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        newresult.Elapsed = elapsedhours + ":" + elapsedminutes + ":" + elapsedseconds + "." + elapsedmillis;
                    }


                    results.Add(newresult);
                }
            }

            //Then add in the entries
            foreach (Result result2 in results)
            {

                var entry = Entries.FirstOrDefault(p => p.BibNumber == result2.ScanBibNumber);
                if (entry != null)
                {
                    result2.EntryId = entry.Id;
                    result2.FirstName = entry.FirstName;
                    result2.LastName = entry.LastName;
                    result2.FormattedName = entry.FirstName + " " + entry.LastName.ToUpper();
                    result2.Gender = entry.Gender;
                    result2.DateOfBirth = entry.DateOfBirth;
                    result2.Club = entry.Club;
                    result2.Team = entry.Team;
                    result2.EntryBibNumber = entry.BibNumber;
                }
                else
                {
                    result2.EntryId = 0;
                    result2.FirstName = "Unknown";
                    result2.LastName = "ATHLETE";
                    result2.Gender = "Unknown";
                    result2.DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now;
                    result2.Club = "";
                    result2.Team = "";
                    result2.EntryBibNumber = "Unknown";
                }

            }
            var sortedresults = new ObservableCollection<Result>(results.OrderBy(c => c.TimingPosition));
            Results = sortedresults;
            OnPropertyChanged("Results");

        }



    }
}
```

Comment: As a sanity check, are you setting `BindingContext` of your view to viewmodel? And in view are you binding to properties in your viewmodel?

Comment: Yeah I am. All the properties are loading in correctly. As I am pulling data from an API the way it works is on page load it gets the data and binds to the XAML and displays it fine. There are buttons on the page to perform functions. These then POST/DELETE to the API, and it retrieves the data again. What it really needs to do is at the end of many of the void methods is (Any I am doing a task run) is to launch LoadResults() and refresh the page when THAT method has finished.

Comment: Hey yo. I noticed you're creating a new instance of a ObservableCollection on each change. When you set bind to the page, I think the object that you've used on first time (which was bound with the page) is not the same you are using after updates. Here is some advices: 1 - Use a single instance of the ObservableCollection and clear it when you need. And 2 - You should manage the property by the public object. It will help you to avoid a lot of `OnPropertyChanged` calls outside the property. I hope it help

Comment: What I am doing is, in the `LoadResults()` method I am creating new observable collections. However they are all temporary. At the bottom of that method (about 5 lines up) that is where I am setting the public `Results` observablecollection/property to be the content from my temporary OC. So I _thought_ that was what I was doing :-/